# Problems with Express's functions using Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am making an app that saves and shows books to sell. It's everything ok, but this error began to appear:

> GET http://localhost:3000/api/usuarios 404 (Not Found) zone-evergreen.js:2952

This error appears in two files: 'apuntes' and 'usuarios'

Here is the controller's code:

```
const usu = require('../models/usuario')
const usuarioCtrl = {};

usuarioCtrl.getUsuarios = async (req, res) => {
    const usuarios = await usu.find();
    res.json(usuarios);
}

usuarioCtrl.createUsuarios = async (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body);

    const usuario = new usu({
        nombre: req.body.nombre,
        apellido: req.body.apellido,
        fecha: req.body.fecha,
        registro: req.body.registro,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    await usuario.save();

    res.json({
        'status': 'Usuario Creado'
    });

}

usuarioCtrl.getUsuario = async (req, res) => {

    const usuarios = await usu.findById(req.params.id);
    res.json(usuarios);
}

usuarioCtrl.editUsuario = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const usuario = {
        nombre: req.body.nombre,
        apellido: req.body.apellido,
        fecha: req.body.fecha,
        registro: req.body.registro,
        password: req.body.password
    };
    await usu.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: usuario }, { new: true });
    res.json({ status: 'Usuario Actualizado' });
};
usuarioCtrl.deleteUsuario = async (req, res) => {
    await usu.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
    res.json({ status: 'Usuario Borrado' });
}

module.exports = usuarioCtrl;
```

I'm sure that the index and route's code are right, but I don't know what to do and why this is happening. I have two controllers and two routes files and both have the same logic.

This is my first question in StackOverflow, I thank you for your help. If you need more details about the project, please tell me.

Here's the router:

```
const express=require('express');
const router1 = express.Router();

const ctrl1=require('../controllers/usuarios.controller');

router1.get('/', ctrl1.getUsuarios );
router1.post('/',ctrl1.createUsuarios);
router1.get('/:id',ctrl1.getUsuario);
router1.put('/:id',ctrl1.editUsuario)
router1.delete('/:id',ctrl1.deleteUsuario);

module.exports=router1;
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags, `angular`-tag is for v2 ->

Comment: Plus, we will also need to see the router !

Comment: do you have the `router` call that looks something like: `router.get('/api/usuarios', usuarioCtrl.getUsuario)` ? can you show us that call?

Comment: I'll edit the question to show you the router

Comment: can you make requests to `http://localhost:3000/api/usuarios` from browser and tell us if that's working? what about `http://localhost:3000/usuarios`?

Comment: It's not working. This message appears in the browser:  ```Cannot GET /api/usuarios```. I tried your second option and this message appears: ```Cannot GET /usuarios```

Comment: The same message appears for all operations (post, put, delete)

Comment: How can I send you the entire project?

Comment: It's not complicated, is a little project